# saslauthd multi instance for postfix smtp authentication

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, saslauthd

I have mail server Postfix+Saslauth.
I configure multiple instance for Postfix:

> postfix
>
> postfix-out

and two instances for `saslauth`:

> saslauthd
>
> saslauthd-out

Setting `saslauthd` is for authenticating `Postfix` service and `saslauthd-out` for another instance of it.

For creating second instance of `sasl` I do it this way:

> cp /etc/default/saslauthd /etc/default/saslauthd-out

With this configuration :
     :~#  vim /etc/default/saslauthd-out

```
 DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon postfix-out"
 NAME="saslauthd-out"
 MECHANISMS="pam"
 OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix-out/var/run/saslauthd-out"
```

In configuration of postfix-out (/etc/postfix-out/sasl/smtp.conf):

```
  pwcheck_method: saslauthd-out
```

and for postfix (/etc/postfix/sasl/smtp.conf):

```
  pwcheck_method: saslauthd
```

and when I restart `saslauth` every thing is OK ,

when I try to connect `smtp server` (postfix) every thing is OK , and Authentication was successfull, but in `smtp server` (postfix-out) , connect to smtp is OK, but it can't authenticate and this error has occurred:

```
:~# telnet mail2.example.com 25 
Trying 111.222.333.444...
Connected to mail2.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'. 
220 mail2.example.com ESMTP Postfix (@@DISTRO@@) 
auth plain YWdoc2EAYWdoc2hhbGRvcmFu 
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: no mechanism available
```

Logs :

```
Nov 30 09:17:47 mail4 postfix-out/smtpd[4361]: connect from unknown[111.222.333.444]
Nov 30 09:17:58 mail4 postfix-out/smtpd[4361]: warning: SASL authentication problem: unknown password verifier 
Nov 30 09:17:58 mail4 postfix-out/smtpd[4361]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Nov 30 09:17:58 mail4 postfix-out/smtpd[4361]: warning: unknown[111.222.333.444]: SASL plain authentication failed: no mechanism available
Nov 30 09:18:04 mail4 postfix-out/smtpd[4361]: disconnect from unknown[111.222.333.444]
```

what is the problem?

Comment: What's in your logfiles?

Comment: Log file added.(mail.log)

Comment: Hmm, the password verifier should be the value of `pwcheck_method`, so your error message `unknown password verifier` means postfix can't connect to the saslauthd-out socket. Did you create a symlink to `/var/run/saslauthd-out` ?

Comment: Yes , I create symlink /var/run/saslauthd-out with /var/spool/postfix-out/var/run/saslauthd-out .

Answer (score 1):

`pwcheck_method` is a configuration option for the Cyrus SASL library. Possible values are `auxprop`, `saslauthd`, `pwcheck` and `authdaemond`. `saslauthd-out` is not supported here. You configuration needs to be like this

/etc/default/saslauthd-out:

```
DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon postfix-out"
NAME="saslauthd-out"
MECHANISMS="pam"
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix-out/var/run/saslauthd-out"
```

/etc/postfix-out/sasl/smtp.conf:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
saslauthd_path: /var/spool/postfix-out/var/run/saslauthd-out/mux
```

somewhere in /etc/postfix-out/main.cf:

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = smtp 
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
cyrus_sasl_config_path = /etc/postfix-out/sasl
```

I just setup a VM with that configuration and it works.

`/var/spool/postfix-out/var/run/saslauthd-out` has to exist, although personally i would prefer it to be more like `/var/spool/postfix-out/saslauthd-out`. But that is your decision.

Comment: When I do that ,this error has occurred :
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: generic failure
,,with this log : 


Dec  1 02:26:40 mail postfix-out/smtpd[12858]: warning: SASL authentication failure: cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file or directory

,,Dec  1 02:26:40 mail4 postfix-out/smtpd[12858]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed

,,Dec  1 02:26:40 mail postfix-out/smtpd[12858]: warning: unknown[ip]: SASL plain authentication failed: generic failure

Comment: That is probably because of your symlink from `/var/run/saslauthd-out` to `/var/spool/postfix-out/var/run/saslauthd-out`. Stop saslauthd-out remove the symlink and start saslauthd-out. If your /var/run is tmpfs, it's gone after the next reboot anyways.

Comment: I just updated my answer to include all the configuration needed.

Comment: If remove symlink , saslauthd can't give pid . I don't understant your comment , Please explain it. tnx.

Comment: What I mean is the symlink is unnecessary. You already told saslauthd-out to put everything in `/var/spool/postfix-out/var/run/saslauthd-out` using -m switch. It will contain mux, mux.accept and the pid-file (saslauthd.pid) but all libsasl needs is the (full) path to mux and it gets that location from saslauthd_path in smtp.conf.

Comment: Ok , Tnx, I do it but can't authenticate and this error occurred :

Comment: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure \n
This error(logfile)\n
Dec  1 08:55: mail postfix-out/smtpd: connect from unknown[IP]\n
Dec  1 08:55: mail postfix-out/smtpd: warning: SASL authentication problem: unable to open Berkeley db /etc/sasldb2: No such file or directory\n
Dec  1 08:55: mail postfix-out/smtpd : warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed\n
Dec  1 08:55: mail postfix-out/smtpd: warning: unknown[IP]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure\n
Dec  1 08:55:17 mail postfix-out/smtpd: disconnect from unknown[IP]\n

Comment: Looks like you have sasldb mixed in somewhere in the configuration. Do you have `auxprop_plugin: sasldb` in smtp.conf? If so remove that as you seem to want PAM.

Comment: No , I haven't any configure by `auxprop_plugin` , I connect to smtp server by pam users , It work for another postfix instance fine and authenticate Ok.

Comment: I added too more config-lines for main.cf, please add those.

Comment: tnx for your attention , but with this change above error occurred again.\n what is meaning this line : \n `SASL authentication problem: unable to open Berkeley db /etc/sasldb2: No such file or directory` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11783/discussion-between-lsmooth-and-superuser)